# A prettier way to handle spaces with enters in YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

This is more of a styling question. I have this ugly piece of code:

```yaml
- name: download something
  shell: "wget https://www.{{ my_var }}\
    a_string\
    {{ a_very_long_string_to_show_what_i_mean }}"
```

In my opinion, this looks very ugly. Since the URL must be a 'whole', without spaces and quoting and whatnot, I need to escape each newline with a `\`. Yuck.

However, I can't use breaks, e.g. `>` or `|` since that will include spaces in the end result, and the code will error.

Following the ansible-lint guidelines, I do not want the string size on a single line to be larger than something about 84 characters. In this example, when I have to download a file, I can't simply put the string on a single line.

Expected output:

```yaml
- name: pretty download something
  shell:
    wget https://www.{{ my_var }}
    a_string
    {{ a_very_long_string_to_show_what_i_mean }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I can't use breaks, e.g. `>` or `|` since that will include spaces in the end result, and the code will error.

That is actually only an half true statement.
You can combine it with the [whitespace control mechanism](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) of Jinja to remove those unneeded whitespaces.

Basically, adding a dash to the opening or the closing of an expression blocks do trim the extraneous whitespace or carriage return before or after it.

---

Given:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          wget https://www.{{ my_var -}}
          a_string
          {{- a_very_long_string_to_show_what_I_mean -}}
      vars:
        my_var: example.org/
        a_very_long_string_to_show_what_I_mean: _foo
```

This yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: wget https://www.example.org/a_string_foo
```

---

Note that in:

```
wget https://www.{{ my_var -}}
```

The dash on the opening moustache is not needed, because there is no extra space before that variable.

Comment: My man, thanks, exactly what I want.

Comment: As a response to your edited answer: then why are 2 dashes required on the last variable? In this case, a_very_long....

Comment: Just sanity clean up. If that's indeed the end of the URL, you can also leave it out.

Comment: Actually `-}}` at the end will remove the newline and whitespace before `vars:`, leading to incorrect YAML since `vars:` will be appended to the value of `msg`.

Comment: @flyx That's not how Ansible templating works; the YAML is parsed well before any Jinja processing happens, so it is impossible for template whitespace manipulation to affect the YAML.

Comment: @flowerysong Hmm some day I need to write a cheat sheet of the differences of all those YAML/templating combos…

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε  How would I configure Ansible to make the output without spaces in this situation: https://pastebin.com/iyddbDf7

Comment: You could use an empty comment block: https://pastebin.com/5VDix36Q